# how to add a foreign key (one to many) in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys, entity

i have two entities 'Panier' and 'Reservation' i want to add a one to many  foreign key (the Entity 'Panier' can have many 'Reservation' and 'Reservation' has only one 'Panier' id ) , so i have to add a foreign key 'id' of 'Panier' in my Reservation entity class . 
this is my  Reservation class :

class Reservation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateReservation", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $datereservation = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="quantite", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $quantite;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="total", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
 */
private $total;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="seat", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $seat;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="payer", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $payer;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nomReservation", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $nomreservation;

/**
 * @var \Event
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $event;

/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

/** @Entity */
class Reservation {

  /**
   * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Panier", inversedBy="reservations")
   * @JoinColumn(name="panier_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
   private $panier;

}

/** @Entity */
class Panier {

   /**
    * One Panier has many Reservations. This is the inverse side.
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Reservation", mappedBy="panier")
    */
    private $reservations;

    public function __construct() {
       $this->features = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```